# Why automatic currying in ML family languages

Tags: language-design, currying, ml

ML family languages have automatic currying - where a function call with two arguments is considered to apply them one at a time, `f x y` = `(f x) y` - whereas other language families don't.

Is this just a historical accident, or is there a technical reason for this?

Note that I am *not* asking whether automatic currying is net good or bad (that's a subjective judgment). I'm asking whether it synergizes with other features of ML family languages so as to make it more natural to include in those languages, and if so, what are those features and what is the nature of the synergy? Or conversely, are there features of other language families that would clash with any attempt to provide automatic currying?

Edit: in addition to the given answers, it occurs to me that there is probably another factor: if you are writing the compiler *in* a language with pattern matching, it's okay for the AST to be more complex, which means it's okay for the conventional 'call with a tuple' construct to be a compound term. So given that the compiler is often written in its own language, automatic currying and pattern matching go well together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Standard ML supports tuples (and other records) and pattern-matching, it also supports a *non*-currying model:

```
fun add (x, y) = x + y
```

So curried functions are just one option, and the special support for defining them is just syntactic sugar (albeit very important syntactic sugar for writing idiomatic ML code). There's no reason that a language like JavaScript *couldn't* offer the same syntactic sugar:

```
// Analogous to fun (f o g) x = f (g x) -- not actually valid JS:
function compose(f)(g)(arg) {
    return f(g(arg));
}
```

but since it's not so common for JavaScript functions to immediately return a function, this syntactic sugar wouldn't be so useful there. (Of course, this is somewhat circular: what's common in a language is shaped by what the language makes easy, and a language makes things easy because they're common in that language. But that's true of all language features, and not specific to this one.)

Interestingly, even in Standard ML, the special curried-function syntax only works for function *declarations* (`fun ...`), not for function *expressions* (`fn ...)`. So I can write

```
val op o = fn f => fn g => fn x => f (g x)
```

but not

```
val op o = fn f g x => f (g x)         (* illegal *)
```

In [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), by contrast, even function expressions support automatic currying; for example, `(\ x y z -> x + y + z) 3 4 5` evaluates to `12`. (Haskell also treats currying as more central in one other respect, namely that infix operators are curried functions, unlike in Standard ML where infix operators are functions that take a pair.)

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is no accident.

For one, it simplifies the language: no need to introduce functions with multiple arguments as a separate concept; every function has exactly one argument. Multiple arguments can be expressed either by tuples or by currying.

Second, it is very convenient in practice, as various patterns relying on partial application (e.g., higher-order functions, combinator libraries, etc) demonstrate..

Comment: "For one, it simplifies the language: no need to introduce functions with multiple arguments as a separate concept"

Sure, but either tuples or currying accomplish that. Why have both? Why not just tuples since you also want those for data structures?

Comment: @munificent, functions are first-class in functional languages, so the expressiveness underlying currying is already there. The question boils down to whether to provide a little bit of syntactic sugar for *conveniently* writing function definitions in curried style. And the answer is, why not, since it's trivial to support and currying is useful (see second point), and slightly more concise, too.

Comment: Sure, I'm not claiming it's not worthwhile sugar to add but your earlier claim was that currying simplifies the language, which I don't think is the case. Once you have tuples, you no longer need currying to avoid the complexity of multi-arg fns. Currying is just a nice bonus on top of that.

Comment: @munificent, sure, once you have tuples. Admittedly, this part of the argument is rather technical -- in principle, a language could have product types (e.g., records), but no structural tuple types.

Comment: Sure, tuples are just records whose field names are integer constants. ;) My point is that if you have *some* way to compose larger data structures, you can always use that same mechanism to compose multiple parameters to only-single-arity functions.